# F# object lists

Tags: list, f#, dynamic-list

For a project of mine, I need a list that can carry multiple types, and I don't want to do any casting, so I've tried using `obj list`s. Here's some example code to show something that should work, but for some reason doesn't:

```
type Fruit() =
  member this.Kind = "I'm a tasty fruit!"

type Apple() =
  inherit Fruit()
  member this.Kind = "I'm a crispy apple!"

type Cherry() =
  inherit Fruit()
  member this.Kind = "I'm a juicy cherry!"


> (new Fruit()).Kind
val it : string = "I'm a tasty fruit!"

... // And so on; it works as expected for all three fruits

> let aFruit = [new Fruit()]
val aFruit : Fruit list = [FSI_0002+Fruit]

> aFruit.Head.Kind                          // Works just fine
val it : string = "I'm a tasty fruit!"

> let fruits : obj list = [new Fruit(); new Apple(); new Cherry]
val fruits : obj list = [FSI_0002+Fruit; FSI_0002+Apple; FSI_0002+Cherry]

> fruits.Head                               // Okay, so we can extract items just fine. It also kept the property!
val it : obj = FSI_0002+Fruit {Kind = "I'm a tasty fruit!";}

> it.Kind                                   // This doesn't work. Why? What am I missing?
 error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Kind' is not defined
```

Comment: shouldn't it be member it.Kind? I personally do not use F#. Just a vee bit.

Comment: The this or it can actually be called anything; its the identifier to the current object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `it` has type `obj` as the list is an `obj list` and `obj` has no `.Kind` member.  You can use the parent type - like

```
let fruits : Fruit list = [new Fruit(); new Apple(); new Cherry()];;

val fruits : Fruit list = [FSI_0003+Fruit; FSI_0003+Apple; FSI_0003+Cherry]
```

and then access it with:

```
fruits.Head.Kind;;
val it : string = "I'm a tasty fruit!"
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I tried that before but it didn't let me because an instance Apple is not an instance of Fruit... And I thought that if it did work, you had to upcast it! I guess not! Also, members still work, right?

Comment: There are some situations where you have to cast - but it is just `a :> Fruit` so pretty simple.  Members are obviously working just fine.

Comment: Oh, I actually need to declare the base member `abstract` then `override` it